# requirements list in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I want to create a request list. The layout of the table should be the same as in this picture:

[image]

Dates:

```
tablewidth = textwidth
column "F W" -> width = 1cm -> c
column "Nr." -> width = 1cm -> c
column "Bezeichnung" -> width = as wide as possible -> l
column "Werte, Daten, Anforderungen" -> width = as wide as possible -> l
column "Zust." -> width = As broad as "Zust." occupies -> c
column "Status" -> width = As broad as "Zust." occupies -> c
column "Bemerkungen" -> width = As broad as "Bemerkungen" occupies -> l
```

The gray line should appear on each page.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[
BCOR=5mm,           % Binderkorrektur von 5mm vorsehen
DIV=10,             % Seite in X Kästchen einteilen (Siehe Koma-                    Script Guide)
fontsize=12pt,      % Schriftgröße 12 Punkte
oneside,            % Einseitig
parskip,            % Paragraphen nicht einrücken
bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis                     aufnehmen
listof=totoc,       % Sonstige Verzeichnise ins
fleqn            % gibt Formeln linksbündig aus  
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline, plainfootsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%Tabelle
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.0cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c c c l c c c @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{B. Buiiea GmbH \& Co. KG} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{Datum der Erstellung: 01.01.17} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}r@{}}{Aktueller Stand: 02.01.17}\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Konstruktion und} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Index: 00} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Entwicklung} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{Erstellt von: Max Mustermann} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{@{}c@{}}{Anforderungsliste}\\
\multicolumn{7}{@{}c@{}}{Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{@{}c@{}}{Projekt-Nr.: 1234567890}\\
\multicolumn{7}{@{}c@{}}{Projektname}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{@{}c|@{}}{Anforderungen} & F = Fest\\
\multicolumn{6}{@{}c|@{}}{}           & W = Wunsch\\
\midrule
\makecell[c]{F \\ W} & Nr. & Bezeichnung & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\bottomrule
\caption{Anforderungsliste}
\label{tab_anforderungsliste}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

I propose two consecutive tables,: a small table first, up to `Project Name`, the the main table, with  repeated heads at the top of each page.

```
\documentclass[
BCOR=5mm, % Binderkorrektur von 5mm vorsehen
DIV=10, % Seite in X Kästchen einteilen (Siehe Koma- Script Guide)
fontsize=12pt, % Schriftgröße 12 Punkte
oneside, % Einseitig
parskip, % Paragraphen nicht einrücken
bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
listof=totoc, % Sonstige Verzeichnise ins
fleqn % gibt Formeln linksbündig aus
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline, plainfootsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%Tabelle
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, cellspace, bigstrut}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newlength{\lastcolwd}
\settowidth{\lastcolwd}{Bermerkungen}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.0cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\newcommand\mymidrule{\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}}
\newcommand\mybottomrule{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}}
\newcommand\mytoprule{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Sl|X|Sl @{}}
  \mytoprule
  \makecell[lc]{B. Buiiea GmbH \& Co. KG \\ Konstruktion und\\ Entwicklung}
   & Datum der Erstellung: 01.01.17 \par\mbox{}\par Erstellt von: Max Mustermann
   & \makecell[lc]{Aktueller Stand: 02.01.17 \\ Index: 00\\ \mbox{}} \\
  \mymidrule
  \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{Anforderungsliste} \\
  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{3}{@{} >{\centering}m{\textwidth}@{}}{Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{Projekt-Nr.: 1234567890} \\
  \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{Projektname}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Sc| Sc |X| X| c | c | >{\RaggedRight\bigstrut}m{\lastcolwd}}
  \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{-4ex}{0pt}
  \multicolumn{6}{@{}c|@{}}{Anforderungen} & \makecell[lt]{F = Fest \\W = Wunsch}\\
  \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}\makecell[c]{F \\ W} & Nr. & Bezeichnung &
  \bigstrut Werte\par\ Daten \par Anforderungen & Zust. & Status & Bermerkungen \\
  \mybottomrule
  \endfirsthead
  \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}\makecell[c]{F \\ W} & Nr. & Bezeichnung &
  \bigstrut Werte\par\ Daten \par Anforderungen & Zust. & Status & Bermerkungen \\
  \mybottomrule
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{1} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\bfseries Funktionen} \\
  \hline
  F & 1.1 & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & xy & & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{1} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\bfseries Funktionen} \\
  \hline
  F & 1.1 & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & xy & & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{1} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\bfseries Funktionen} \\
  \hline
  F & 1.1 & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & xy & & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{1} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\bfseries Funktionen} \\
  \hline
  F & 1.1 & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & xy & & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \\
  \hline \noalign{\penalty-5000}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{1} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\bfseries Funktionen ! ! ! } \\*
  \hline
  F & 1.1 & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & xy & & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{1} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\bfseries Funktionen} \\
  \hline
  F & 1.1 & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. & xy & & Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \par Hier steht ein Text. Hier steht ein Text. \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]